# Changing font of a text in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I have been trying to change the font of the output in the window using the Win32 API. Here is what I did, but it does not work. What should I do?

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
hFont = CreateFont(y_position, closest_match, escapement, orientation, FW_DONTCARE,
    no_italic, no_ul, no_xout, ANSI_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DRAFT_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,
    TEXT("Tekton Pro")/*"SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT"*/);
SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
TextOut(hdc, 50, y_position, TEXT("test"), strlen("test"));
// TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
DeleteObject(hFont);
```

Comment: Leaking resources big time here

Comment: Yes.... Hopefully you call DeleteObject(hFont);  after usage

Answer (score 9):

After creating your font object `hFont`, you have to call `SelectObject()` to assign it to the `hdc`.  When you are done using your font, call `SelectObject()` again to restore the old font (so it is not leaked) before destroying your font:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
hFont = CreateFont(y_position, closest_match, escapement, orientation, FW_DONTCARE,
    no_italic, no_ul, no_xout, ANSI_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DRAFT_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH,
    TEXT("Tekton Pro")/*"SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT"*/);
hOldFont = (HFONT) SelectObject(hdc, hFont); // <-- add this
SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
TextOut(hdc, 50, y_position, TEXT("Hello from Ugur"), strlen("Hello From Ugur"));
SelectObject(hdc, hOldFont); // <-- add this
DeleteObject(hFont);  // <-- add this
// TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```